# Issue with migration from an existing installation of AWS ALB Ingress Controller (v1) to the new AWS Load Balancer Controller (v2)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

We have an existing ALB Ingress controller deployment in EKS cluster having image as v1.1.9:

docker.io/amazon/aws-alb-ingress-controller:v1.1.9

Now we are in process of migrating from AWS ALB Ingress Controller (v1) to the new AWS Load Balancer Controller (v2).

Following this document : https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/deploy/upgrade/migrate_v1_v2/

It mentions that **first need to manually uninstall existing AWSALBIngressController**, but missing details like how to uninstall it. Tried to find AWS EKS documentation on this but everywhere it is mentioned without commands or other details for actual manual uninstallation.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would remove all the ingress objects that use ALB Ingress controller (will cause downtime). To do so, `kubectl get ingress -A`, go through each one of them and see if it has annotation -

```
annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
```

Then use `kubectl delete ingress <ingress-name>` to delete the ingress objects.

To uninstall the controller itself, you need to figure out how it was installed.

1. Check if helm was used - `helm ls -A`. If you find a release for ALB ingress controller, then simply delete the release using `helm delete <release-name>` command.
2. If helm was not use, then go through the installation of v1.1 docs - https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v1.1/guide/controller/setup/#installation and undo the steps. For example -

```
kubectl delete -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller/v1.1.9/docs/examples/rbac-role.yaml

kubectl delete -f alb-ingress-controller.yaml
```

Make sure to `kubectl get` before deleting the resources blindly and tweak the delete commands according to your setup, thanks.